# Install ffmpeg on centos server

Tags: ffmpeg, centos, ffmpeg-php

while installing ffmpeg on my centos server.I get this error while running ./configure: checking for ffmpeg headers... configure: error: ffmpeg headers not found. Make sure ffmpeg is compiled as shared libraries using the --enable-shared option

```
cd /usr/local/src 
wget http://downloads.sourceforge.net/project/ffmpeg-php/ffmpeg-php/0.6.0/ffmpeg-php-0.6.0.tbz2?use_mirror=nchc 
tar -xjf ffmpeg-php-0.6.0.tbz2 
phpize 
./configure 
make make 
install
```

Comment: Are you compiling `ffmpeg` or something else that uses the `ffmpeg` libs. Because it looks to me like you are doing the latter. Post some details, full commands, console output.

Comment: i am compiling ffmpeg..pls look my edited code

Comment: No, that's the ffmpeg extension for `php` which uses `ffmpeg`. You need to do a `yum install ffmpeg-devel` if you really want to compile the extension...

Comment: sorry actually i need ffmpeg extension for php

Comment: still i coundn't install this package....please help me

Comment: That iteration of "php-ffmpeg" is long dead and will not work with any supported version of ffmpeg. See the [ffmpeg-php tag](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/ffmpeg-php/info) and [FFmpeg Wiki: PHP](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/PHP) for more info.

Answer (score 0):

Try using ffmpeg auto installer, you need to dounload a package with required plugins, its free,
you can refer this link for demo
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EaaT7vj8K2s

Here you will get complete installation package
http://ffmpeginstaller.com/

It will take around 30 mins for complete installation, you just need to keep an eye on command prompt.

Answer (score 0):

You can Install FFMPEG on CENTOS by just Downloading rpm package of ffmpeg from ffmpeg.org and place at a particular location in ur Centos Server.
by Configuring the binary you can easily use ffmpeg commands.
Hope this Will help you :)

Answer (score 0):

I hope this helps.

If ever you're trying to install ffmpeg to CENTOS 7, you might want to try this since this is what I did since I have a unsolvable problems with my packages.

Download compressed ffmpeg and extract it to the server: https://www.johnvansickle.com/ffmpeg/ in this case I used ffmpeg-git-amd64-static.tar.xz.

1. Extract the xz file. cmd: tar -xf filename.tar.xz
2. Extract the tar file if it's still in tar file. cmd: tar -xvf filename.tar
3. Go to the extracted file’s directory.
4. You must see these files under the folder[image]
5. Try the command ./ffmpeg -version[image]
6. Add it to the environment variable so that you can use the ffmpeg globally. Assuming that the ffmpeg main folder is contained in usr/ffmpeg, get the original PATH value using the command: echo $PATH , copy the original path value add it with the path of the ffmpeg directory (e.g. :usr/ffmpeg) and add it to the PATH environment variable with the command: export
   PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/root/bin:/usr/ffmpeg
7. You should be able to use the ffmpeg command now with cmd: ffmpeg -version[image]
8. Try to convert files now example: cmd: ffmpeg -i input.webm output.mp4 and it should all work now.